# matplotlib only plotting date instead of given datetime variable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot candle sticks but for some reason, the plot does not grab the entire DateTime variable. But only the date. Plotting all candles on the same X axis rather than all 15 min as the data is given in.

Following code.

```
        ##  PLOT Candles
        plt.figure()

        #define width of candlestick elements
        width = .5
        width2 = .05

        #define up and down prices
        up = df[df.close>=df.open]
        down = df[df.close<df.open]
        print(up)
        #define colors to use
        col1 = 'green'
        col2 = 'red'
        col3 = 'blue'
        col4 = 'grey'

        #plot up prices
        plt.bar(up.index,up.close-up.open,width,bottom=up.open,color=col1)
        plt.bar(up.index,up.high-up.close,width2,bottom=up.close,color=col1)
        plt.bar(up.index,up.low-up.open,width2,bottom=up.open,color=col1)

        #plot down prices
        plt.bar(down.index,down.close-down.open,width,bottom=down.open,color=col2)
        plt.bar(down.index,down.high-down.open,width2,bottom=down.open,color=col2)
        plt.bar(down.index,down.low-down.close,width2,bottom=down.close,color=col2)
        
        plt.show()
        exit()
```

Following is the print of up
[image]

[image]

print(df[:5].to_dict())

> {'open': {Timestamp('2016-01-14 08:15:00'): 1.08719,
> Timestamp('2016-01-14 08:30:00'): 1.08735, Timestamp('2016-01-14
> 08:45:00'): 1.08674, Timestamp('2016-01-14 09:00:00'): 1.08674,
> Timestamp('2016-01-14 09:15:00'): 1.08671}, 'high':
> {Timestamp('2016-01-14 08:15:00'): 1.08749, Timestamp('2016-01-14
> 08:30:00'): 1.08739, Timestamp('2016-01-14 08:45:00'): 1.08734,
> Timestamp('2016-01-14 09:00:00'): 1.08722, Timestamp('2016-01-14
> 09:15:00'): 1.08673}, 'low': {Timestamp('2016-01-14 08:15:00'):
> 1.0869, Timestamp('2016-01-14 08:30:00'): 1.08673, Timestamp('2016-01-14 08:45:00'): 1.08669, Timestamp('2016-01-14
> 09:00:00'): 1.08666, Timestamp('2016-01-14 09:15:00'): 1.08582},
> 'close': {Timestamp('2016-01-14 08:15:00'): 1.08736,
> Timestamp('2016-01-14 08:30:00'): 1.08673, Timestamp('2016-01-14
> 08:45:00'): 1.08673, Timestamp('2016-01-14 09:00:00'): 1.08671,
> Timestamp('2016-01-14 09:15:00'): 1.08618}, 'volume':
> {Timestamp('2016-01-14 08:15:00'): 2181, Timestamp('2016-01-14
> 08:30:00'): 1738, Timestamp('2016-01-14 08:45:00'): 1938,
> Timestamp('2016-01-14 09:00:00'): 3010, Timestamp('2016-01-14
> 09:15:00'): 2734}}

Comment: Could you share a part of your dataframe to be able to try something please?

Comment: it's really hard to post it here as it keeps reformatting. It's basically just EURUSD. I posted it some of it here https://justpaste.it/37ppn  After converting to dataframe I have to do df.set_index('date', inplace=True) for different reasons mentioned here.

Comment: Nope, the problem is maybe something inside your dataframe (format, timestamp...) Just give me the 5 first rows with this: "df[:5].to_dict()" and copy/paste the result in your question. Otherwise I'll pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's do this!

First things first:
https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/

> The New API This repository, matplotlib/mplfinance, contains a new
> matplotlib finance API that makes it easier to create financial plots.
> It interfaces nicely with Pandas DataFrames.
>
> More importantly, the new API automatically does the extra matplotlib
> work that the user previously had to do "manually" with the old API.

```
pip install --upgrade mplfinance
#or
import mplfinance as mpf
```

Given the sample I asked you:

```
data = {'open': {'2016-01-14 08:15:00': 1.08719, '2016-01-14 08:30:00': 1.08735, '2016-01-14 08:45:00': 1.08674, '2016-01-14 09:00:00': 1.08674, '2016-01-14 09:15:00': 1.08671}, 'high': {'2016-01-14 08:15:00': 1.08749, '2016-01-14 08:30:00': 1.08739, '2016-01-14 08:45:00': 1.08734, '2016-01-14 09:00:00': 1.08722, '2016-01-14 09:15:00': 1.08673}, 'low': {'2016-01-14 08:15:00': 1.0869, '2016-01-14 08:30:00': 1.08673, '2016-01-14 08:45:00': 1.08669, '2016-01-14 09:00:00': 1.08666, '2016-01-14 09:15:00': 1.08582}, 'close': {'2016-01-14 08:15:00': 1.08736, '2016-01-14 08:30:00': 1.08673, '2016-01-14 08:45:00': 1.08673, '2016-01-14 09:00:00': 1.08671, '2016-01-14 09:15:00': 1.08618}, 'volume': {'2016-01-14 08:15:00': 2181, '2016-01-14 08:30:00': 1738, '2016-01-14 08:45:00': 1938, '2016-01-14 09:00:00': 3010, '2016-01-14 09:15:00': 2734}}
```

Transform "data" into a `df` and convert the `index` to the right format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df
```

Then plot it!

```
mpf.plot(df, type='candle')
```

Output:

[image]